# Hooking aftermarket drain hose to Frigidaire dishwasher

Tags: plumbing, drain, dishwasher, hose

I would like to replace the 8' factory drain hose that came with my Frigidaire dishwasher (model FMB330RGC0) with a 6' hose to save space under the sink. I ordered a replacement hose, which needs to have a right angle fitting on the dishwasher side. However, once I unplugged the old hose, I noticed that, even though the diameter of the hose fitting is the same, the factory one has some ribbing:

[image]

to match the stub on the dishwasher:

[image]

The aftermarket 6' hose has a plain fitting with no ribbing:

[image]

I thought Frigidaire purposely did this to proprietarize and prevent the aftermarket products from being used on their appliances so I called to see if I can order theirs in 6' but they didn't have it and the lady I talked to didn't know any more technical details.

Based on the pictures, can you tell if I can somehow adapt the new plain hose to go over the stub that has ribbing?

Comment: there's not a lot of pressure, so it should be fine as long as it doesn't leak right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to fit the hose over the fitting to the washer. Then get a hose clamp and install it over the hose and tighten it.

Comment: Looks like it's working so far. Fingers crossed

Comment: Yup, +1; the ribbing is just an extra safeguard against blow-out. I normally prefer the spring-type clamps because they self-tighten over time when the hose rubber softens with age, but I think I would use a screw-type clamp on that outlet pipe. And crank it good and tight.

Answer (score 0):

Its not worth the effort of the hose. I found the correct OEM hose at a local repair shop. I suggest the correct hose per model.

Comment: You may note that in the original question it was indicated that the OEM _doesn't offer_ a 6' replacement hose for this particular model of dishwasher. If you're able to locate one, it would be quite helpful to post a link to it for the benefit of the OP (and others), though after 18 months, his "not worth the effort" solution is probably still working quite well.